# Get css of Visio SharePoint WebPart within an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, sharepoint, css-selectors, visio

Some Microsoft Visio has to be shown in SharePoint Online, and the only option is to embed it in an Iframe WebPart within SharePoint.

The only odd is to remove the bottom menu of the Visio, and there are many nested css within the iframe - we are not finding a dynamic way to remove Visio menu - any pointers would be appreciated.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
    var iframe = document.getElementById("Iframe");
    iframe.onload = function(){
        $("#Iframe").contents().find(".mypage-header2").hide();
    }
</script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to do that with javascript/jQuery, because the domains Visio runs on and your code runs on are different, for security reasons. You might want to consider using API `Application.showToolbars` to control the toolbar.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/visio/visio.application?view=visio-js-1.1#showtoolbars